# How can I do something right before the session expire(destroy)

Tags: node.js, session, express

Hi I am using `expressjs` for my web application, and I use the `session` middleware, my question is that how I can do something right before the session expire?

For example, I store something in the session, and I set the `req.session.cookie.maxAge` to 60000(1 minute), when the session timeout, I want to save the data in the session to disk, how I can do this? I checked the API and the `destroy` function only support `callback`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using `connect-session` there's nothing like session expiration event.

Sessions expire either :

- on the client (when cookie gets outdated). There's no way to know about it until a request is made so there's a danger that the event will never get triggered.
- in the session store, usually using some form of time-to-live. Not all session stores support events, so notification can't be done in general.

You can, however try implement your own check using `setTimeout()` - when it times out check if the session's expiration date is sufficiently close to now and do whatever you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am using connect-session. I thought about setTimeout(), but it may increase the CPU overhead...I think if there is no way to do that, I will eventually use setTimeout()...thanks

Comment: @Chun it shouldn't increase CPU overhead too much. Just set the timeout to the expected time-to-live of the session.